# Unity 2D game object moving up in curve?

Tags: unity, 2d, movement, curves

How can I make a rigidbody2d game object moving up curve like the attached screenshot?[image: moving up in curve]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is anything in specific not working the way you expect it to? The more you can tell us about the problem you're having and its context in your game (eg. what gameplay feature is this serving?), the better we can tailor answers to be useful to your needs.

Comment: Hi, it's a projectile shooting from bottom to top of the screen. I have tried something like below but it's far from the screenshot,  
float x = transform.position.x + 3;
float y = transform.position.y + 5;
movement = new Vector2(x, y) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
transform.Translate(movement);

Comment: @Eddi Did you search online how to move objects in a curve ?